# Multiple Apps - One SSL

Tags: ssl

I'm trying to configure a domain and SSL to run multiple Facebook apps through the SSL.

What I need advice on is routing the apps through the SSL without actually hosting them on that server. Ideally they would be hosted on the client's server.

Any advice on how to do this?

**UPDATE**

Following the advice from the replies I have setup a domain which houses my Facebook apps under one SSL. So far this is working well. Thanks guys. :)

Comment: As @MadHatter pointed out, you absolutely *must not* set up a reverse proxy that would decrypt SSL connections and then proxy them via HTTP to a third server over the public Internet. That would be *evil*.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to set up a [reverse proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) to accept and decrypt incoming HTTPS connections, then proxy them to your client's HTTP server *over your private network*. In other words, this reverse proxy server that you're setting up will be co-located with your client's server.

There are multiple tools that can do this for you, including Squid, Nginx, and Apache itself. Tutorials are linked below in order to explain the specific steps for each platform.

- [Squid SSL reverse proxy tutorial](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Reverse/SslWithWildcardCertifiate)
- [Nginx SSL reverse proxy tutorial](http://blog.thamini.com/xat/howto-add-some-additional-security-your-openerp-web-client-ssl-using-nginx)
- [Apache reverse proxy with mod_ssl](http://blogs.thehumanjourney.net/oaubuntu/entry/apache_mod_proxy_mod_ssl)

Comment: Apache link is missing :)

Answer (score 0):

Advice, in brief?  Don't.  The end-user will, on seeing a decently-signed SSL certificate, assume that their information is secure in transit.  You haven't said how you're taking traffic from your SSL-decrypt point to the client's server(s), but unless it's at least as well encrypted, you're exposing your end-users' data behind the scenes.

If you are very sure that it is as well encrypted, then OK, this isn't such a worrying idea, and Miles is right, you're essentially running a proxy server.  You can do this in apache with `mod_rewrite`, getting your local apache to go off *sub rosa* and get content from the clients' servers, and feed it back over the existing HTTPS connection to the end-user.  There are a number of other ways of doing it, too, but I'd do it with apache and mod_rewrite.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

The last thing I want is to risk the user's data being compromised during transition, so I think I'll stick to a straight forward host and request from the same server.